Unable to load template 'file:CRM/EntityTemplates/EntityTemplate.tpl
Please some help to debug this error
Thank you
CiviCRM 5.74.4 on Wordpress 6.5.5 PHP   8.2.20  Smarty 4
The error occurred when /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fadd&reset=1&ct=Individual I would create a new contact
 [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Unable to load template 'file:CRM/EntityTemplates/EntityTemplate.tpl'"
  "code" => null
  "exception" => SmartyException {#5715
    #message: "Unable to load template 'file:CRM/EntityTemplates/EntityTemplate.tpl'"
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php"
    #line: 196
    trace: {
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php:196 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:238 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:116 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php:85 {
        CRM_Core_Region->{closure}
        › $smarty->assign('snippet', $snippet);
        › $html .= $smarty->fetch($snippet['template']);
        › $smarty->assign('snippet', $tmp);
      }
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php:161 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/block.crmRegion.php:26 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/it_IT/ef/1f/a6/ef1fa64a4a34f04aa798a72fb9b1132034ebaf7b_0.file.CMSPrint.tpl.php:107 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php:123 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php:114 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php:217 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php:386 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/it_IT/fc/ab/53/fcab53f831b68079fc4d780ba901ade225ff090f_0.file.wordpress.tpl.php:31 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php:123 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php:114 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php:217 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:238 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:116 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:117 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:83 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php:98 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:296 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1231 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:348 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 { …}
      /home/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:259 { …}
    }
  }
]


Does the error go away if you revert to default Smarty rather than Smarty 4?

No,  there is this error prior update and with  Smarty 4

It sounds like you're using my "Entity Templates" extension, which has not been updated in some time.  I just pushed an update that changes the boilerplate extension code to be compatible with modern CiviCRM.  I just released a new version on Github.  If you upgrade your problem should be fixed.

Totally exact, Thank you Jon!
